# How do I disable Bind?

Tags: mac, bind

I followed these instructions in order to enable Bind.

http://intridea.com/2010/6/2/using-bind-locally-on-os-x-for-easy-access-to-subdomains?blog=company

Now I want to disable it and get back to a clean system. How do I do it?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions directly beneath "'A few notes on the setup instructions:'" which explain how to keep a backup of all configuration files you were going to change?

Comment: @PriceChild: I didn't keep backups :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring 'checking commands' Those instructions have done a few things...

1. Create `/etc/rndc.conf`
2. Create `/etc/rndc.key`
3. Edit `/etc/named.conf`
4. Create `/var/named/appname.zone`
5. Running `launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.isc.named.plist`
6. ...and in step 8 edited some system preferences.

So....

- I suggest you remove (but keep backups) the 3 files you created above.
- Remove the entry you added in `/etc/named.conf`
- Run `launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.isc.named.plist`
- Undo the changes you made in 'System Preferences' in step 8.

---

**Keep backups...**

- ...before you do things
- ...before you undo things
- ...when instructions say to

You definitely don't want to play around with named.conf too much **so make a backup of the file before you undo things as i advise above!**

Comment: That did it :) thanks. You are right about not messing with named.conf. I am switching to http://pow.cx/ so that I don't have to worry about configuration anymore.

Comment: Good stuff and good luck!